# How / where to set try catch in cordova app for whole project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to set one try catch for whole application.
    if i will get any error in my project then I can redirect to login page.

Comment: Why would you redirect to the login page if any error occurs? I understand for several parts but the whole projekt?

Comment: resolving the hanging issue

Comment: you can redirect to home page also instead of login page.

Comment: yes i can its another thing but the thing is how to set try catch for redirecting.

Comment: You can use `window.onerror` to capture errors and then handle them appropriately (though I don't think that redirecting to login is appropriate here &mdash; you should instead try to work around the error and/or prompt the user to send an error report your way so you can debug the issue). 

Don't use this as a catch-all, though; this is just present in case of an unexpected condition that you didn't catch anywhere else. You should ideally catch close to the code that can generate the error rather than try to do it all at the top level.

Comment: Thanks @KerriShotts 
I want to handle unexpected error thats-why I am trying to apply try catch for whole project.